# angularJs component and controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I have created angular component and the code looks below:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('App', ['ngMaterial']).component('autoComplete', {
            template: '<div layout="column" ng-cloak>\
                        <md-content class="md-padding">\
                            <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">\
                                <md-autocomplete ng-disabled="$ctrl.isDisabled"\
                                    md-no-cache="$ctrl.noCache"\
                                    md-selected-item="$ctrl.selectedItem"\
                                    md-search-text-change="$ctrl.searchTextChange($ctrl.searchText)"\
                                    md-search-text="$ctrl.searchText"\
                                    md-selected-item-change="$ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"\
                                    md-items="item in $ctrl.querySearch($ctrl.searchText)"\
                                    md-item-text="item.display"\
                                    md-min-length="0"\
                                    placeholder="Search State">\
                                <md-item-template>\
                                <span md-highlight-text="$ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>\
                                </md-item-template>\
                                <md-not-found>\
                                No states matching "{{$ctrl.searchText}}" were found.\
                                <a ng-click="$ctrl.newState($ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>\
                                </md-not-found>\
                                </md-autocomplete>\
                                <br />\
                            </form>\
                        </md-content>\
                    </div>',
            controller: function DemoCtrl($timeout, $q, $log, $http) {
                $log.info('Called');
                var self = this;

                self.simulateQuery = false;
                self.isDisabled = false;

                // list of `state` value/display objects
                self.states = loadAll($http);
                self.querySearch = querySearch;
                self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
                self.searchTextChange = searchTextChange;

                self.newState = newState;

                function newState(state) {
                    alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constitution for " + state + " first!");
                }

                // ******************************
                // Internal methods
                // ******************************

                /**
                 * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
                 * remote dataservice call.
                 */
                function querySearch(query) {
                    //var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : self.states,
                    //    deferred;
                    //if (self.simulateQuery) {
                    //    deferred = $q.defer();
                    //    $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve(results); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
                    //    return deferred.promise;
                    //} else {
                    //    return results;
                    //}
                    var allStates;
                    return $http.get("/Home/GetStates", { params: { q: query } })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        allStates = response;
                        return allStates.data.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
                            return {
                                value: state.toLowerCase(),
                                display: state
                            };
                        });
                    })
                    //$http({
                    //    method: 'GET',
                    //    url: '/Home/GetStates'
                    //}).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    //    allStates = response;

                    //}, function errorCallback(response) {
                    //    alert(response);
                    //    return false;
                    //});
                }

                function searchTextChange(text) {
                    $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
                }

                function selectedItemChange(item) {
                    $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
                }

                /**
                 * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
                 */
                function loadAll($http) {
                    //var allStates;
                    //$http({
                    //    method: 'GET',
                    //    url: '/Home/GetStates'
                    //}).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    //    allStates = response;
                    //    return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
                    //        return {
                    //            value: state.toLowerCase(),
                    //            display: state
                    //        };
                    //    });
                    //}, function errorCallback(response) {
                    //    alert(response);
                    //    return false;
                    //});            
                }

                /**
                 * Create filter function for a query string
                 */
                function createFilterFor(query) {
                    var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

                    return function filterFn(state) {
                        return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
                    };

                }
            }
        })
})();
```

and i have created a one more controller in new javascript file and it looks below.

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("App", []);
    var TestController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.Display = "Test Display";
    };
    app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", TestController]);
}());
```

Here is my HTML

```html
<html ng-app="App" ng-cloak>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial'
         */
        angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial']);
        
    </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/TestAngular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Component/auto-complete.component.js"></script>
    <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->

    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="Display" />
        {{Display}}
    </div>
    <auto-complete></auto-complete>
    
</body>
</html>
```

when tried to run this HTML, i am getting Testcontroller registration error. But if i remove *auto-complete.component.js* then TestController is working fine. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Shouldn’t you have your var `app` global, and always use this one instead of redeclaring `angular.module('App'..` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing with your module declaration, either declare it once, or do it right.

## Doing it right

Once you’ve declared your module, you can access it with

```
angular.module('App')
```

So in your html file nothing changes, but in **both** other files, replace `angular.module('App',[..]) by`angular.module('App').

This is the best practice to achieve it, keeping each component separated in isolated `(function(){ .. })()` blocks

## Declaring it once

For your issue, I solved by changing the first called script (inline in html) to:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial']);
```

Then I used this variable instead of redefining a new module each time :

```
(function(app){
   // controller or component here
}(app));
```

This did the trick, however this migth be some more complicated module *overwritting*. Moreover, you should avoid global variable as such

My TestController:

```js
(function (app) {
    var TestController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.Display = "Test Display";
    };
    app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", TestController]);
}(app));
```

My autocomplete component:

```js
(function (app) {
    'use strict';
    app.component('autoComplete', {
      // ...
    })
})(app);
```

Comment: Well I did it and I got a result, maybe there is a misunderstanding.. I’ll try to detail

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but you should look for [Sravan’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41801610/6320039) which is more accurate. Or I can update mine now that I know exactly how it works, just choose!

Answer (score 2):

**Error: Module should be created only once in all the application.**

You have created a module for a component and also for the controller which is wrong. Create for one and use in the second.

In your controller,

**`var app = angular.module("App", []);`**

Should be,

**`var app = angular.module("App");`**

**Controller:**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("App");
    var TestController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.Display = "Test Display";
    };
    app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", TestController]);
}());
```

Check the line,

```
var app = angular.module("App");
```

Comment: @Sathish, please check my answer and ask if any doubts.

Comment: I tried your code. But its throwing a same error. Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]

Comment: did you declare the module only once?

Comment: Yes.. Now my controller looks like ' var app = angular.module("App");
    var TestController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.Display = "Test Display";
    };
    app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", TestController]);' . I did this and ran the code

Comment: any changes to be made in HTML or Component Class ?

Comment: @Sathish I tried this version and it work for me. I’ll update my answer

Comment: Yes .. this too works fine .. Thank you and @Ulysse BN